# How to write Simple.Data query to join two tables?

Tags: sql, database, simple.data

I need to write Simple.data queries for following SQL queries can you help me ?

```
SELECT
    Table1.UserID,
    Table1.we, Table1.ba, Table1.re,
    Table1.rtes, Table1.datae, Table1.void,
    Table1.deletee
FROM
    Table1
INNER JOIN 
    Table1 ON UserID.UserID = Table2.UserID  
WHERE
    Table2.clinicId = 11
```

I try it following way

```
db.Table1.FindAll()
         .Where(db.Table1.UserID == db.Table2.FindAll(db.Table2.ClinicID = 11).Select(db.Table2.UserID));
```

but it does not work. I use mysql 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.Table2.FindAllByClinicId(11)
  .Select(
    db.Table2.Table1.UserId,
    db.Table2.Table1.we,
    db.Table2.Table1.ba,
    db.Table2.Table2.re,
    db.Table2.Table1.rtes,
    db.Table2.Table1.datae,
    db.Table2.Table1.void,
    db.Table2.Table1.deletee);
```

That should end up sending this to the database:

```
SELECT Table1.UserId
     , Table1.we
     , Table1.ba
     , Table1.re
     , Table1.rtes
     , Table1.datae
     , Table1.void
     , Table1.deletee
FROM Table1
     INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.UserId = Table2.UserId
WHERE Table2.ClinicId = 11
```

Comment: Thanks .can you tell me how can i select * from Table1 in your answer

Answer (score 0):

you are joining with same table. so you need to join two different tables or join same table giving alias.

```
SELECT Table1.UserID, Table1.we, Table1.ba, Table1.re, Table1.rtes, Table1.datae,
Table1.void, Table1.deletee FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON 
UserID.UserID = Table2.UserID
where Table2.clinicId=11
```

OR

using alias for same table.

```
SELECT t1.UserID, t1.we, t1.ba, t1.re, t1.rtes, t1.datae, t1.void, t1.deletee FROM 
Table1 as t1 INNER JOIN Table1 as t2 ON UserID.UserID = t2.UserID
    where t2.clinicId=11
```

Comment: +1 for using alias , they come handy when u have a lot of tables

Comment: i dont need sql quries i need Simple.Data quries

Answer (score -1):

This should work, you should just say " table1 inner join tabloe2". && condition Table1.UserID = Table2.UserID
where Table2.clinicId=11

```
  SELECT Table1.UserID, Table1.we, Table1.ba, Table1.re, Table1.rtes, Table1.datae,                
  Table1.void, Table1.deletee  
  FROM Table1
  INNER JOIN Table2 
  ON Table1.UserID = Table2.UserID
  where Table2.clinicId=11
```

Comment: i dont need sql quries i need Simple.Data quries